# Flask-marshmallow relationship is working properly returning empty object from child table

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow, flask-marshmallow

I followed flask-marshmallow documentation and written below code, when i query author table i get empty books object from books table. Can you tell me what is the issue I am facing ?

also, i see pycharm is not detecting ma.Nested(), any way how to import it ?

```py
class Author(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    # books = db.relationship("Book", backref="authors")
    # book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("book.id"))


class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255))
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("author.id"))
    author = db.relationship("Author", backref="books")

class BookSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        include_fk = True

class AuthorSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Author

    id = ma.auto_field()
    name = ma.auto_field()
    books = ma.Nested("BookSchema", many=True)


# Creation of the database tables within the application context.
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()

author_schema = AuthorSchema(many=True)
book_schema = BookSchema(many=True)


@app.route('/', methods=["GET"])
def get_hello_world():
    queryDB = Author.query.all()
    result = author_schema.dump(queryDB)
    print(result)
    return jsonify(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to see full data from books table when i query author table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `books` attribute in the `AuthorSchema` is a collection of nested objects. For this reason it is necessary to use `List` in conjunction with `Nested` and the respective schema.
In order not to have to define all attributes individually, I also recommend using [`SQLAlchemyAutoSchema`](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema).

```py
class BookSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        include_fk = True

class AuthorSchema(ma.SQLAlchemyAutoSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
    books = ma.List(ma.Nested(BookSchema))
```

Comment: I update with your suggestion and now i dont see any books objects and i also get this warning from pycharm on ma.Nest()
"Unresolved attribute reference 'Nested' for class 'Marshmallow'"
json data:
```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Venkat"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Venkat"
    }
]
```

Comment: Never mind i figured out. Issue is I added fields in schema "id = ma.auto_field()
    name = ma.auto_field()". Thank you for suggesting.